# Perception: thinking a minority behavior in a minority group is the majority of said group

Tags: perception

I once heard that we tend to have some perception bias : we tend to think that a behavior by a minority of a minority group is in fact the representation of the majority of this minirity group.
Classical example would be that we tend to think that people from another state drive badly. This would come due to the fact that when we see a car driver behaving badly on the road, we will see the license plate from another state and that would ´stick’ better in our memories. And from there, we would generalize that people from that region are bad drivers as we don’t check the license plate of good drivers.
Is there such a thing? If so, is there a term/denomination for such perception bias?
I hope that I was clear enough as English is not my primary language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the term you are looking is [out-group homogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-group_homogeneity#A_self-categorization_theory_account).

> The out-group homogeneity effect is one's perception of out-group
>   members as more similar to one another than are in-group members, e.g.
>   "they are alike; we are diverse". ... Perceivers tend to have
>   impressions about the diversity or variability of group members around
>   those central tendencies or typical attributes of those group members.
>   Thus, outgroup stereotypicality judgments are overestimated,
>   supporting the view that out-group stereotypes are
>   overgeneralizations.